# LiftMaster remote not linking to Genie Garage opener/controller

Tags: garage-door-opener

Googling "[liftmaster remote for genie controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=liftmaster+remote+for+genie+controller&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&sxsrf=AOaemvLd2oJHRmwVJWjJ5U8uLKgswQx5qA%3A1632607336335&ei=aJxPYen2E-iVwbkP2aKkwAc&oq=liftmaster+remote+for+genie+controller&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAxKBAhBGABQAFgAYMSNBWgAcAJ4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAA&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjpytuikJvzAhXoSjABHVkRCXgQ4dUDCA4)", I do find lots of pages about "Genie remote, Liftmaster garage opener", but I haven't come across any info for the other way around, "Liftmaster remote, Genie garage opener".

Indeed I haven't been successful at my attempt to link Liftmaster remote to Genie opener.

1. Is that combination not possible?
2. If it's possible, then what are the steps to do so?

FYI [Liftmaster 893LM remote](https://www.liftmaster.com/893lm-garage-door-clicker/p/G893LM), Genie's opener model <s>is yet to find</s>: [CM7600IC (geniecompany.com)](https://store.geniecompany.com/collections/by-model-pro95-cm7600-cm8600).

Comment: Are they the same frequency, both companies have use several frequencies?

Comment: yeah. probably incompatible frequencies -- your options are to get a new receiver ( that works with your current remotes - and hook into your liftmaster ( since it will have an input signal to activate)

Comment: Thanks for updating with the Genie model number. Does that mean that you still don't have this resolved?

Comment: Yes, with the particular combination of product models, I haven't resolved my issue. However my question is answered so I chose an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the learn button on the garage door opener.  It typically has a color and shape (usually rectangular).

Right on the site you linked it says:
"GDO Learn Button Color Compatibility (Learn Button Color)  Yellow Circle".  This color/shape was introduced in 2011 and determines the frequency and technology used for the remote.

The remote you purchased only works with garage door openers with a yellow circle for the learn button.  You will need to find one which lists compatibility with the button color and shape that matches your own. For reference, it should match one of these:

| Learn Button Color | Antenna Color | Technology | Radio Frequency | Color of LED | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yellow (square) | Gray | DIP Switch | No longer supported | Red | Prior to 1993 |
| White | Gray | DIP Switch | No longer supported | Red | Prior to 1993 |
| Gray | Gray | DIP Switch | No longer supported | Red | Prior to 1993 |
| Green | Gray | Billion Code | 390Mhz | Green | 1993-1997 |
| Red/Orange | Gray | Security+ Rolling Code | 390Mhz | Amber/Yellow | 1997-2004 |
| Blue | Gray | Security+ Rolling Code | 433Mhz | Amber/Yellow |  |
| Purple/Brown | Purple | Security+ Rolling Code | 315Mhz | Amber/Yellow | 2005-2014 |
| Yellow (round) | Yellow | Security+ 2.0 | 310, 315 & 390Mhz | Amber/Yellow | 2011-Current |

Source: https://support.chamberlaingroup.com/s/article/Determine-the-Color-of-the-Learn-Button-on-Your-Garage-Door-Opener

Comment: This is a very thorough answer, thanks! Please edit it one more time to meet SE guidelines by including the source of the chart you included.

Comment: @FreeMan I went through this recently.  Luckily the one I ordered (LiftMaster 374UT) covered the one I had, which was green.  But I was in the same boat, ordered without knowing if it would work.  I'm guessing there are 4 choices of remotes, Prior to 1993, Green/Red/Orange/Pruple/Brown, Blue, and the round yellow 2011+.  Just hope it's not blue, those are rare.

Comment: thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the LiftMaster model you have is not sold as a "universal" remote, but rather only for LiftMaster openers. There's nothing in the documentation about using it with other manufacturer's openers.

Looks like you need to find a different remote.